# Opinions on Best Practice for a Relation that is linked to many other types of Relations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, relation

I have a Rails database for reviewing things at a school. My tables are School, Major, Course, Instructor, Review. The way my team currently has the Review table set up, there are non-nullable foreign keys to each one of the other tables.

My issue with this is that to submit a new review the user would want to fill in only 1 of those foreign keys. Is there a way to do this with Rails? Even if there is, it seems like this would be a better use case for Instructor_Review, Course_Review, etc tables. That also has the (very nice) benefit of being able to customize table attributes for each review.

However, if we were to break up Review into multiple tables, is there a mechanism in Rails for having common columns? The overall_rating attribute would need to be included for every type of review, should the attributes just have the same name or is there a way for Rails to have table Subclasses (I know there is in SQL...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't create different models for the different review types if they are similar (apart from the thing the review is about). This is probably a source of duplication which [should be avoided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Instead, you could use a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). Your review model has one thing the review belongs to (be it a school, a teacher, or an instructor). So lets model it like that. Give it a reference to that thing and the type of that thing (so that Rails knows which class it belongs to).

With polymorphic associations, your classes can be linked like this:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reviewable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
  # ...
end

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews, as: :reviewable
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews, as: :reviewable
end
```

On the database-level this means that your review table just needs *one* foreign key to point at the `reviewable` thing (plus one type column). The review-migration would look like this:

```
class CreateReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reviews do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.references :reviewable, polymorphic: true, index: true, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

`polymorphic: true` lets Rails create the id- and type-column.
For details, please refer to the [`ActiveRecord` documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

PS: There is also [a RailsCast covering this issue](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association). But beware: It's from 2009 - pretty old, but (from a quick glimpse at it) it should still work.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for polymophic relationships.  Basically add a type column on the review and then you have to wire it up correctly.  Here is a great article for that.

http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/understanding-polymorphic-associations-in-rails

The review table will then have your common reviewable columns that will be shared.  The next part is a little more complicated.  You would then setup a review to have an extension.

To explain the extension, this is normally done when you have an entity that can either be a group or user (similar to how your InstructoreReview and CourseReview will by types of reviews).  Those groups/users will have a profile that is similar to the extension of the review.

The ReviewExtension will have it's own table per review that you are extending and most of the time those extensions in their own review_extensions folder under models.

Once that is done you will delegate the common getter and setter methods you are wanting to the extension.

Hopefully this will at least give you enough to get going.